# Elasticsearch query documents where two locations have relative distance

Tags: elasticsearch, geospatial, distance

I can't achieve to only get documents with a maximum distance of 1km between two geopoints of the same document.

I have simple documents like this :

```
{
  start_location: {
      lat: 34.0583,
      lon: -118.2476
  },
  end_location: {
    lat: 33.989521,
    lon: -117.531614
 }
}
```

I want to get all the documents where start_location is located less than 1km from end_location.

Im stuck with this for a while, thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `arcDistance` function within a script:

```
PUT geo
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "start_location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      },
      "end_location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST geo/_doc
{
  "start_location": {
    "lat": 34.0583,
    "lon": -118.2476
  },
  "end_location": {
    "lat": 33.989521,
    "lon": -117.531614
  }
}
```

```
GET geo/_search
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": """
      def distance_in_m = doc['start_location'].arcDistance(
        doc['end_location'].getLat(),
        doc['end_location'].getLon()
      );
      
      return distance_in_m < 1000"""
    }
  }
}
```